# i can retrieve username from firebase and log it but when im trying to bind it doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i can retrieve username from firebase and log it but when im trying to bind it doesn't work
with user name under google id

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://firebaseio.com");
ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).once("child_added",function(snapshot)
{
 var name1 = snapshot.child("name").val();
 $scope.username = name1;
 console.log("username : "+ $scope.username);
 $scope.$apply();

});
```

My firebase JSon

```
{
  "users" : {
    "google:107950469269631469408" : {
      "-KK87pj5tW9EL8hL9To7" : {
        "id" : "google:107950469269631469408",
        "name" : "muzi ngobe"
      },

    }
  }
}
```

This is my View

```
<ion-view title="Reminders" id="page7">
    <ion-content padding="true" ng-controller="loginCtrl" class="has-header">
        <div class="list card">
            <div class="item item-divider">{{username}}</div>
            <div class="item item-body">
                <form class="list">
                    <ion-checkbox>{{username}}</ion-checkbox>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Be specific.  *What* doesn't work?

Comment: i've declared name1 and assigned $scope.username to it. now binding username to my view doesn't work. it doesn't display anything. but i'm able to log the value.

Comment: Do you have any kind of error logs that we could go off of?  That would be infinitely valuable.

Comment: No. im only getting the username i've logged

Answer (score -1):

Use `$scope.apply()` to initiate the digest cycle, if the population is happening in an not angular-aware way.